# CURL (PHP lib) : Referer

Tags: php, curl, http-headers

Is there a difference between this expression :

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.somesite.com');
```

and this one :

```
$headers = array(
    ...
    'Referer: http://www.somesite.com',
    ...

);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

Comment: Looks like no, no difference. Just, sometimes, oneliner is more elegant, than messing with headers, and that gets rid of `Referrer: ` typo error - PHP wil yell at us if we mistype CURLOPT_REFERER

Comment: ok, so I suppose it is the same thing with :

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'key=value')

and 

$headers = array(
    ...
    'Cookie: SESSION=avalue',
    ...

);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

Comment: Yeah, but, `Cookie: ` or `Set-Cookie: ` ? Stop wondering and use convenience `curl_setopt($,CURLOPT_*,$)` method. Also, most of IDE will highlight proper constants, and you'll know, if you mistyped something.

Comment: ok, thanks for the explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

No, it's the same. If you have many headers its more redable in form of array.